# Should web apps be embedded in pages on websites?

Tags: javascript, html, webassembly

I'm new to web apps and trying to wrap my head around how they fit into a website, or if they entirely take the place of a website.

Currently I have a website that is simply a server that serves static HTML pages, with some JS embedded in. This works fine, but is kind of janky for more interactive components, where my JS is doing a lot of destroying and creating HTML elements dynamically. I would like to replace these pages of my website with web apps, which I can write in a more type-safe language (like Rust) that compiles to WebAssembly. Can I then embed this compiled web app on my website page?

Is this something regularly done in web development? I may be entirely getting the role of web apps wrong here, but it seems that this use case would be a good fit. If so, how would this normally be done? With a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Don’t get too hung up on the meaning of “web app”. In the end anything that’s getting rendered is creating DOM elements, either manually by you, or by the browser via HTML. Replacing portions of web pages with components is quite common (and you already are). The mechanism to do so is arbitrary; as long as the browser can run the end result it doesn’t matter. How it gets into the page depends on what you’re using; generally they’re rendered into a placeholder DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an `<iframe>` tag to hold your web app
This will not affect the parent code
For example:

```
<iframe 
    srcdoc=`
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </body>
        </html>
`></iframe>
```

Is that what you want?